# SharePoint Add-in is not available in Web Part (App Part) gallery - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, app-part, web-part-gallery

I've developed SharePoint Add-in (**SharePoint hosted**) with an app part so it can be added to SharePoint page. The problem I'm facing now is that the app part is not available from **App part** (or **Web part**) gallery so a user can't add it into a page in **SharePoint Online**. Microsoft made it clear that only Add-in installed with **web scope** (as opposed to **tenant scope**) will be available in App Part gallery. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to figure out how to install it with web scope. There are no instructions or How-To around. Am I missing something here? Does anyone know what needs to be done to make an app part available on SharePoint host site?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

David

Comment: What was the feature scope you mention in Add-in while development

Comment: The feature scope is **Web**. Please note that this shouldn't be confused with Add-in scope which could be **Web** or **Tenant**. For more information see [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/tenancies-and-deployment-scopes-for-sharepoint-add-ins).

Comment: Ok fine , have you checked your catalog site (site content) to install the add-in

Comment: @Sunilsahu Do you mean **organisation's app catalog** by **catalog site**? If so then yes. I've deployed it to the app catalog and I'm able to install it. It just doesn't show up in SharePoint Online Web Part gallery. It does in SharePoint on-premises.

Comment: So you have uploaded the .app to catalog site and to a site where you need to install the add-in ,did you tried searching in the site content for the add-in by the name you have created the app.
Just for a refference if you might be missing something
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-sharepoint-hosted-add-in-app-to-sharepoint-online-in-office-365/

Comment: @Sunilsahu I don't have a problem installing the add-in. It is installed and visible under Site Contents. But this add-in comes with App Part which is missing in Web Part gallery (when you edit a page and want to drop app part into the page).